# How to find the first instance of element1 or element2 using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I go about getting the first instance of an INS element OR the first instance of a DEL element depending on which is displayed first?

Using jQuery, I can get the first of each element in a div using this:

```
$("#output").find("ins").first();
$("#output").find("del").first();
```

In the following html:

```
<div id="output">
   This is some text with some <ins>added text</ins> or maybe some <del>deleted text</del>
</div>
```

I'd like to get the INS element because it appears first.

But in this version:

```
<div id="output">
   This is some <del>deleted text</del> and also some <ins>added text</ins>.
</div>
```

I'd like to get the DEL element because it appears first.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#output").find("ins,del").first();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the first element within #output, then you could do:

```
$('#output > *').eq(0)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Tevh/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#output1 > ins,#output1 del").first()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a6dLH/